# What are the differences between using development tool and not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome 61.

I am facing a problem that if I use post method (javascript) to send the form data to a server (not owned by me)  and the server sometimes received a null value. I did tried about 100 times, about 20-30% of the trials are null value.
But If I open the development tool and do the same thing, the server always received the value as expected.

So, what are the differences between using development tool and not using the development tool? 
(I have asked in chrome forum before, someone told me that there are no difference, but why the results are not the same)

Thank you.

Edit:
Here is the code of the javascript

```
<form name="aForm" action="${requestScope.theServerURL}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="SomeParam" value="${requestScope.someValue}">                </input>
</form>
```

I did sent the request by keep trying in Chrome, not looping by code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*received a null value*"? How did you send the requests using JS, can you post the code please? How did you send so many of them, did you just put them in a loop?

Comment: I've edited the post. The null values means if the server recevied the parameter "SomeParam" by request.getParameter("SomeValue") it gives null.

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript, rather like a serverside template.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your cache is disabled when your developer console is opened.

You can toggle off this behaviour by un-checking the "Disable cache" checkbox.

[image: Disable cache in Network Tab]

Comment: So, If I want to ensure that the form data is sent to the server, I need to enable "disable cache" in development tool?

Comment: POST requests would never be cached, though.